# Samsung Smart TV Play Youtube Video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, samsung-smart-tv

I'm making a Samsung Smart TV application. I need to play youtube videos.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I tried [youtube js api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) but when the function `playVideo()` is executing the video just starts loading but not playing. 
I have Samsung Smart TV 2012 so the SDK is 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check if your youtube video has granted access for mobile devices.

Second you have to disable advertisements on that video - as videos with advertisements doesn't work yet on TV devices.

Sometimes it takes a while after playVideo() to start playing the video, especially when you bind to some player events, so try to wait half or one minute.

If this won't help, please paste your code here - youtube embedding and your JS calls and I'll try to help.

**EDIT**

Try to use flash embedding like in [Samsung docs](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/flash/create_flash_app/tut_flash_app_task.html#_Embed).

As a movie parameter pass the src to [YouTube API player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="playerObject">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?&enablejsapi=1"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
</object>
```

And use this methods:

```
var ytPlayer = null;
function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
  ytPlayer = document.getElementById('playerObject');
  if (ytPlayer) {
    ytPlayer.addEventListener('onStateChange','onChange');
    ytPlayer.addEventListener('onError', 'onError');
    ytPlayer.cueVideoById('i4iDWXstrWY'); //load video for play http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4iDWXstrWY
  } else {
    alert("error");
  }
}
function onChange(newState) {
  //Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5)
  switch (newState) {
    case 5:
      ytPlayer.playVideo();
      break;
  }
function onError(errorCode) {
  alert(errorCode);
}
```

When the player is ready, the API will call the `onYouTubePlayerReady` callback function. I think that in your solution you are missing the `cueVideoById` method. As it is said in [YT API doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#playVideo)

> Plays the currently **cued/loaded** video.

Comment: so it didn't worked. if i wait a minute the video just ends without playing. just like you watched the video but stuck on first frame. i use [sfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) provided by google. then i have a div <div id="ytapiplayer"></div> and the code i execute on `handleShow()` is `var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" }; var atts = { id: "myytplayer" }; swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/<someytlink>?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);`. to start de video i use `ytplayer.playVideo();`

Comment: thank you very much, but something doesnt work, and i cant figure it out. i implemented some alerts in code to see whats happening. so when the state is 5 the video just dont start. i tried different videos and some of them returned error 150. on forums i found that this error is happening when the video is no good for embedding. but  the videos that i use are new and dont generate any error. its seems like the playVideo() doesnt work. also the states are changing in this orther 5, 3, 1. then i called playVidee() when the state is 1 and again nothing.. any idea?

Comment: you should fire `playVideo()` only once - on 5th state. You say you get then 3 (Buffering) and 1 (Playing) so from YT API side everything is working. Did you check it on your PC browser - is it working?.... Oh - one thing more - Have you set parameter `<flashplayer>y</flashplayer>` in your config file?

Comment: in my pc its not working due to flash restriction, i check anything directly on tv. and i didnt include flashplayer...

Comment: something realy wierd is happening when i included <flashplayer> tag all the videos started and the sound worked fine, but no youtube player wash shown, so i added style="width:800; height: 480;". now the player is visible but not all videos are starting... i need to make more tests

Comment: Great. As I said on the beginning - movies with adverts and no-mobile option won't work. Try to test them on your Android YouTube player.

Comment: About playing on the browser - when you setup webserver on your local machine and use your network IP instead of localhost it should work - debugging on browser is much more easier.

Comment: well i think you are right, i have like 10 movies and first two of them are new (and they dont work), the others work perfectly. but i tried to watch them on my android phone and they just work fine even the new ones.. and no advertisment on them.. even with mobile browser they work

Comment: i have a server on my PC and i tried to test there, but the console says cant load "$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js"

Comment: `$MANAGER_WIDGET` about that yes. But in most cases you don't need Samsung API for basic tests. For example the YouTube player - doesn't need it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I really shouldn't be telling you guys this because you'll be able to make apps that compete with mine... but out of frustration with Samsung I will tell you: just host the darn thing as a webpage on a web server (using whatever YouTube API you like, or no API and just changing up the embed code on page load), control which video it plays using a querystring argument, then iFrame it into your Samsung Smart TV app. YouTube has severe embedding restrictions if you try and embed in an app that is not a web page... so stick in web page, then stick web page in app.

This is the general architecture you use for ANY in-app content on a Samsung Smart TV that needs to run in a web browser. The Samsung browser is blessed with being an HTML5 browser that also supports Flash. Samsung Smart TV apps allow IFraming of web content with absolutely no security restrictions. Put 2 and 2 together and you can pretty much do whatever you want on these glorified toasters... keeping in mind that you want to UNLOAD these IFrames (setting their SRC attribute to "" using JQuery is an adequate way to do this) when you change scenes because they do not unload themselves and these TVs have very little RAM.

Have fun guys :)

Comment: FYI. This WORKS for videos with advertisements.